# 3 dB Power Divider Used as Power Combiner S Matrix Explanation

Tags: rf, microwave

I'm trying to understand the operation of an ideal RF power combiner.

Below is the scattering matrix of such device. (i.e. Wilkinson Power Divider)

\$[S] = {\frac {-j}{\sqrt {2}}}{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}}\$

I know how the division works but I'm confused as to how power combination works.

If we were to send a wave from port 2 with an amplitude of A, and in same phase a wave with amplitude of B from port 3 we should get A+B in port 1 since the waves can't go anywhere else in the device.

But i fail to explain this with scattering parameters. \$[b] = [S].[a]\$

In our case \$ [a] = {\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\A \\ B \end{bmatrix}}\$

If we do the matrix scalar multiplication we get:

\$ [b] = {\begin{bmatrix} {\frac {-j}{\sqrt {2}} (A+B)} \\0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}}\$

So we got \$ \frac {-j}{\sqrt {2}}(A+B) \$ at port 1 instead of \$ (A+B)\$.

Where did the rest go? Same thing goes for magic tee as well.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: `1/sqrt(2)*(A + B)` is correct. If `A = B`, you'll have `2/sqrt(2)*A` which is twice the power of `A`. It didn't go anywhere.

Comment: @Jason If we apply A from port 2 and 3 at the same time the total input is 2A in your case. Then we got A*sqrt2 at the output. 2A to 1.414*A therefore something is missing.

Comment: I don't follow what you're saying. If you apply signal `A` to both port 2 and 3, port 1 will be `1/sqrt(2)*(A + B)=2A/sqrt(2)` which is still twice the power of A.

Comment: @Jason

If we apply waves in same phase both with amplitude of A volts.

You are agreeing that the output will be 2A divided by sqrt of 2. Which equals to A times sqrt of 2.

But our total applied input is 2*A which is not the same thing as A*sqrt2



Our input of 2*A does not equal to output of 1.414*A

Comment: Yes. Conservation of energy. `|2*A/sqrt(2)|^2 = 2A^2` which is TWICE the power of A. If the answer were `2A` then `|2*A|^2 = 4A^2` which is 4x the power of A.

Comment: Ok let me phrase it this way:

With what you are saying then if i apply waves with power of P from both ports (in same phase) since we take the square of the scattering matrix we should get S21^2 = 1/2. Only half of the power would be transmitted from port 2 to port 1. 

If thats the case (S21^2=1/2) when we apply power of P from port 2 and 3 total input power is 2P and total output power is P. Which still doesnt make sense to me.

I understand now what you meant though

Comment: Thank you @Jason I now understand what you are saying. I never stopped to think about the fact that it combines power not voltages directly. I thought we would get A+B in voltage as well.

Comment: No worries - I thought that the first time I was thinking through the problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum port of a Wilkinson is a superposition of the S-Matrix. Your answer is correct.

\$ [S] = {\frac {-j}{\sqrt {2}}}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \$

The sum port is a super position of signals at port 2 (`A`) and 3 (`B`):

\$ s = {\frac {-j}{\sqrt {2}}}A + {\frac {-j}{\sqrt {2}}}B = {\frac {-j}{\sqrt {2}}}(A+B)\$

If `A = B` this would reduce to

\$ 2{\frac {-j}{\sqrt {2}}}A\$

Which is twice the power of `A`:

\$ |2{\frac {-j}{\sqrt {2}}}A|^2 = 2A^2\$

Therefore, no power is lost.

Please note: this only true for correlated signals. If random signals are used in `A` and `B` it becomes the sum not super-position.